# How to convert a byte array to a string under a restrictive character set?

Tags: java

I would like to apply a cryptographic hash to an IP number and have the hash be in the character set "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_".

My trials so far:

```
    String ipWithSecret = secret + "123.123.123.123";
    byte[] ipBytes = ipWithSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] mdBytes = md.digest(ipBytes);
    System.out.println("MD5:      " + mdBytes);
    System.out.println("US ASCII: " + new String(mdBytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    System.out.println("Hex:      " + HexBin.encode(mdBytes));
    System.out.println("Base64:   " + Base64.encodeBase64String(mdBytes));        
    System.out.print("Binary:   ");
    for (byte b : mdBytes) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(b & 255 | 256).substring(1));
    }
```

outputs:

```
MD5:      [B@6d6f6e28
US ASCII: :???RN???z?}k^?
Hex:      3A8BB1881E524EDFEFE67AFF7D6B5E9D
Base64:   OouxiB5STt/v5nr/fWtenQ==
Binary:   00111010100010111011000110001000000111100101001001001110110111111110111111100110011110101111111101111101011010110101111010011101
```

Besides the hex, nothing is even remotely acceptable.  My available alphabet is much larger than the hex one and, because I have to deal with a length limit of 16 characters, I would like to get hash string shorter.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

**Answer**
I modified John's answer a little bit so credit goes to him.  Here's my code that also handles collisions somewhat:

```
    String secret = "secret";  //config file, do not store in code
    Set existingMdBase64Alt = new HashSet(Arrays.asList("OouxiB5STt_v5nr_", "ouxiB5STt_v5nr_f"));
    String ipWithSecret = secret + "123.123.123.123";
    byte[] ipBytes = ipWithSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] mdBytes = md.digest(ipBytes);
    String mdBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(mdBytes);
    String mdBase64Alt = mdBase64.replace("+","_").replace("/","_" );
    System.out.println("Debug: " + mdBase64Alt.substring(0, 16));
    while (mdBase64Alt.length() > 16 && existingMdBase64Alt.contains(mdBase64Alt.substring(0, 16))){
        mdBase64Alt = mdBase64Alt.substring(1);
        System.out.println("Debug: " + mdBase64Alt.substring(0, 16));
    }
    System.out.println("Final: " + mdBase64Alt.substring(0, 16));
```

Comment: Note that an IP address is just four bytes (0-255x4), start there instead of the string form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, don't reinvent the wheel: use [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). That's the general "shorter than hex, but still printable ASCII" solution. There are various base64 options available, depending on which version of Java you're using etc. If there's nothing in the core framework you're using, I like the [iharder.net public domain implementation](http://iharder.net/base64).

However, that's not *really* going to help you here. An MD5 hash is 16 bytes - so unless you've got 256 characters at your disposal (to represent each byte with a single character) you're going to end up with more than 16 characters, just because of the amount of information you're trying to represent.

As noted in the comments though, an IPv4 address is just 4 bytes. Frankly, hashing that isn't going to obscure it very much, as hashing the whole address space is eminently feasible...

Comment: Base64 has the characters "+" and "=" while my character set has "_".  Not a perfect match but I can use string substitution on those and combine them. Then truncate the base64 encoded string.  That will increase collisions but the likeliness of it is probably still acceptable.  For the small domain problem of IPs I'll just add a secret.

Comment: @Claus: Yes, your alphabet is effectively painful as it has 63 characters - it's hard to use 63 characters efficiently for arbitrary octet encoding, whereas the 64 (+padding) characters of base64 allows 4char=3byte encoding very cleanly. You can remove the possibility of collisions entirely though by encoding (however you want) the 4 bytes of actual data... it's not clear what you're *really* trying to achieve with this, but using MD5 on a 4-byte value fundamentally seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I want to use cryptographic hashes of IPs that fit my character set.  Primary requirement is that the original IPs can't be guessed.  The secondary to keep collisions to a minimum.  Of course it has to fit into 16 characters as well.

Comment: @Claus: "Primary requirement is that the original IPs can't be guessed." I can't see how you're going to achieve that. Even with salting, guessing the original IP address based on the hashed version just consists of running through the 2^32 possibilities with the single salt. That wouldn't be *cheap*, but it wouldn't be *terribly* hard...